# ESRI Printing service not able print ArcGIS JS API 3.33 RasterLayer

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to [Print](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/print-amd.html) map where the layer in the web application is a [RasterLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/rasterlayer-amd.html)

The slider in the web app mask's the RasterLayer.

I am using ArcGIS JS API 3.33

Following is the code smaple

NOTE: To run the sample you would need to update the printing service URL at line number 127

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>Raster Layer with Pixel Filter</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.33/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.33/esri/css/esri.css">

<style>
html, body, #map
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#status
{
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  border: solid 1px #FFF;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  z-index: 99;
}
.shadow
{
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 8px;
}
#footer
{
  height: 90px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 30;
}

      /* make all dijit buttons the same width */
      .dijitButton .dijitButtonNode, #drawingWrapper, #printButton {
        width: 160px;
      }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.33/"></script>
<script>
 require([
        "esri/map",
        
        "esri/domUtils",
        // "dojo/parser",
        // "dojo/dom",
        // "dojo/dom-construct",
        "dojo/on",
        "dijit/registry",
        "esri/layers/RasterLayer",
        "esri/geometry/Extent",
        "esri/SpatialReference",
        "dijit/form/HorizontalSlider",
        "dojox/form/RangeSlider",
        "dijit/form/HorizontalRule",
        "dijit/form/HorizontalRuleLabels",
        "esri/layers/ImageServiceParameters",
        "esri/layers/MosaicRule",
        "esri/layers/RasterFunction",
        "esri/layers/DimensionalDefinition",

         "esri/toolbars/draw", "esri/dijit/Print",
        "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer", "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
        "esri/layers/LayerDrawingOptions",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol", "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol", 
        "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol", "esri/graphic",
        "esri/renderers/ClassBreaksRenderer",
        "esri/config",
        "dojo/_base/array", "esri/Color", "dojo/parser", 
        "dojo/query", "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-construct", 
        "dijit/form/CheckBox", "dijit/form/Button",

        "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/domReady!"
      ], function(
        Map, 

         domUtils, on, registry, RasterLayer, Extent,
    SpatialReference, HorizontalSlider, RangeSlider, HorizontalRule, HorizontalRuleLabels,
    ImageServiceParameters, MosaicRule, RasterFunction, DimensionalDefinition,

        Draw, Print,
        ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer,
        LayerDrawingOptions,
        SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol,
        SimpleFillSymbol, Graphic,
        ClassBreaksRenderer,
        esriConfig,
        arrayUtils, Color, parser, 
        query, dom, domConstruct, 
        CheckBox, Button
      ) {
  parser.parse();
  var currentMin, currentMax;
  var rasterUrl = "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/ScientificData/SeaTemperature/ImageServer";

  //set up slider
  var slider = registry.byId("pixelSlider");

  var initExtent = new Extent(-130, -68, 150, 68, new SpatialReference(4326));
  var map = new Map("map", {
    extent: initExtent,
    basemap: "gray"
  });

   var printer = new Print({
    map: map,
    url: "UPDATE_YOUR_PRINTING_SERVICE_URL"
  }, dom.byId("printButton"));
  printer.startup();


  var sliderMin = -3;  //min sea surface temp of -3 deg C
  var sliderMax = 37;  //max sea surface temp of 37 deg C
  slider.minimum = sliderMin;
  slider.maximum = sliderMax;
  slider.value = [sliderMin, sliderMax];

  // hook up slider events
  slider.on("mouseup", setPixelFilter);
  slider.on("change", setPixelFilter);

  //set up slider labels
  var sliderLabels = new HorizontalRuleLabels({
    container: "bottomDecoration",
    labels: [sliderMin.toFixed(0).toString(), sliderMax.toFixed(0).toString()]
  }, domConstruct.create("div", {}, dom.byId("pixelLabels")));

  //set up blue to red color ramp inside array
  var colorRamp = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    colorRamp.push( [i, 30, 255 - i] );
  }

  /***************************************************************
  * This image service has multiple dimensions including depth and time.
  * If you are only interested in viewing temperatures at a specific time
  * and at a specific depth, use dimensional definisions
  **************************************************************/

  var dim = [];   //define dimensional definition as array
  //DEPTH: show only temperatures at sea surface
  dim.push(new DimensionalDefinition({
    variableName: "water_temp",
    dimensionName: "StdZ",  //water depth
    values: [0],  //sea surface or 0ft
    isSlice: true
  }));
  //TIME: only show temperatures for the week of April 7, 2014
  dim.push(new DimensionalDefinition({
    "variableName": "water_temp",
    "dimensionName": "StdTime", //time temp was recorded
    "values": [1396828800000], //Week of April 7, 2014
    "isSlice": true
  }));

  var defaultMosaic = {};
  defaultMosaic.multidimensionalDefinition = dim;
  var params = new ImageServiceParameters();
  params.mosaicRule = new MosaicRule(defaultMosaic);

  //the service has a default "Stretched" function and a "None" function, we want original data "None"
  var rf = new RasterFunction();
  rf.functionName = "None";
  params.renderingRule = rf;

  //Define the raster layer and add to map
  var rasterLayer = new RasterLayer(rasterUrl, {
    opacity: 1,
    pixelFilter: maskPixels,
    imageServiceParameters: params
  });
  map.addLayer(rasterLayer);

  rasterLayer.on("update-start", function () {
    domUtils.show(dom.byId("status"));
  });
  rasterLayer.on("update-end", function () {
    domUtils.hide(dom.byId("status"));
  });

  // The pixel filter
  function maskPixels(pixelData) {
    if (pixelData == null || pixelData.pixelBlock == null) {
      return;
    }
    if (currentMin === undefined || currentMax === undefined) {
      setPixelFilter();
    }
    var pixelBlock = pixelData.pixelBlock;
    var pixels = pixelBlock.pixels;
    var mask = pixelBlock.mask;
    var numPixels = pixelBlock.width * pixelBlock.height;
    var minVal = rasterLayer.bands[0].min;
    var maxVal = rasterLayer.bands[0].max;
    var factor = 255.0 / (maxVal - minVal);
    if (pixels == null) {
      return;
    }
    var p1 = pixels[0];
    var pr = new Uint8Array(p1.length); //set up array for red values
    var pg = new Uint8Array(p1.length); //set up array for green values
    var pb = new Uint8Array(p1.length); //set up array for blue values

    if (mask == null) {
      mask = new Uint8Array(p1.length);   //mask = new Uint8Array(p1.length);
      pixelBlock.mask = mask;
    }
    var p = [];
    //if pixel value lies between slider min and max, display it (set value to 1)
    //if not, don't display it (set the value to 0)
    for (var i = 0; i < numPixels; i++) {
      mask[i] = (p1[i] >= Math.floor(currentMin) && p1[i] <= Math.floor(currentMax)) ? 1 : 0;

      //apply color based on temperature value of each pixel
      if (mask[i]) {
        p[i] = Math.floor((p1[i] - minVal) * factor);
        pr[i] = colorRamp[p[i]][0];  //red
        pg[i] = colorRamp[p[i]][1];  //green
        pb[i] = colorRamp[p[i]][2];  //blue
      }
    }

    pixelData.pixelBlock.pixels = [pr, pg, pb];  //assign rgb values to each pixel
    pixelData.pixelBlock.statistics = null;
    pixelData.pixelBlock.pixelType = "U8";
  }

  //Redraw raster layer and dynamically change text on slider move
  function setPixelFilter() {
    var val = slider.get("value");
    currentMin = Math.floor(val[0]);
    currentMax = Math.floor(val[1]);
    if (val) {
      dom.byId("pixelVal").innerHTML = "Currently displaying locations with sea temperatures from " + currentMin + "°C to " + currentMax + "°C";
    }
    else {
      dom.byId("pixelVal").innerHTML = "Currently displaying all temperatures.";
    }
    rasterLayer.redraw();
  }
});
</script>
</head>

<body class="claro">
  <div id="map" >
     <div id="printButton"></div>
    <div id="status">
        Loading...
    </div>
    <div id="footer" class="shadow">
      <span style='font-weight: 600; font-size: 130%;' id='elevSpan'>Sea Surface Temperature (°C) on April 7, 2014</span><br><br>
      <div id='pixelVal'></div>
      <div id="pixelSlider" data-dojo-type="dojox/form/HorizontalRangeSlider" data-dojo-props="showButtons:'false', intermediateChanges:'false', slideDuration:'0'">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/HorizontalRule"></div>
        <div id="pixelLabels"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Following is how the app looks like:
[image]

The printing result looks like following:
[image]

Notice the threshold applied for masking values in the web application are not acknowledged by the print service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known limitation of the print service. If a Raster or Imagery layer has a pixel filter, the updated values will not be acknowledged by the print service.

In ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4.x, we have a workaround where you can use a view.takeScreenshot() method:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sceneview-screenshot/index.html

There is no workaround for ArcGIS API for JavaScript 3.x.